# Random sampling for estimating mutual information - Time complexity and sampling error?

Tags: machine-learning, probability, sampling, sample-size, mutual-information

I have a dataset and I want to compute the **mutual information (MI)** for a selected set of variables. The dataset is large enough so that computation of the MI may take undesirably long time. **Can I just take a 10% sample of the data and use it to compute the MI measure?**

I am aware of different sampling techniques including *random sampling, stratified sampling and bootstrapping*. Even though techniques that require computing MI more than once such as bootstrapping or clustering provide good clues about bias and variance, they lead to some extra computational time. I want to compute MI only once. So, preparing a single random sample and using it for estimating MI is a solution. **My concern is how accurate is this solution based on a sample size of 10% of data? What about the sampling error and do I have to pay attention to it?**

**Note:** Regarding computing the MI, I do not assume normality for estimating any probability; rather, a non-parametric method (*i.e.* histogram) is used.

Comment: I would like to share one more idea which came up after posting the question. Since we are using frequency distribution to generate a histogram for probability estimation in the MI, then, as the sample size increases, we will get a better approximation of the probability. Given this assumption, then, a sample size of 10% can be an acceptable sample size. I am still not so certain about this claim and looking for your comments and answers.

Comment: Are your variables continuous or discrete valued? MI is notoriously difficult to estimate, even more so in the continuous case. What kind of precision do you require?

Comment: also bootstrap doesn't correctly correct bias for MI.

Comment: @Memming; I am considering computing MI for continuous variables as for the discrete case, it is much easier. I mentioned in the question, as well, that non-parametric methods such as histogram could be used for discretizing the variable.

Comment: unfortunately, histogram based estimation using the plug-in formula is still biased. I guess if you have a lot of data, it shouldn't be too bad. I recommend Paninski 2003.